# Javascript Label

Tags: javascript, labeled-statements

Mozilla Developer Network states that

Statement 1 : "The labeled statement can be used with break or continue statements. It is prefixing a statement with an identifier which you can refer to."

Statement 2 : "break can be used with any labeled statement, and continue can be used with looping labeled statements."

Question : Does javascript allow labeling any statement or just the loops. If it's just the loop statement? what is relevance of "Statement 2" above from MDN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can label any statement, including a labeled statement. Labels only do something useful when somewhere inside the labeled statement is a context in which break or continue make sense.

Thus

```
pointless: var x = 0;
```

is syntactically OK but the label doesn't (can't) do anything.

To be able to `break` to a label, the `break` needs to be *inside* the labeled statement. A `break` cannot be "inside" a `var` declaration as in the example above, which is why it's not useful. However, this works, and is the typical use of `break`:

```
outerLoop: for (var i = 0; i < matrix.length; ++i) {
  for (var j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; ++j) {
    var inMatrix = matrix[i][j];
    if (somethingWeird(inMatrix))
      break outerLoop;
  }
}
```

If you want to break out of a nested loop structure without having some awkward flags to test, you can use a labeled statement like that.

The slightly mysterious note from MDN that you mention about `break` being available from any sort of statement just means that you can `break` from things that aren't loops:

```
someLabel: if (condition(something)) {
  // code code code
  if (shouldGiveUp())
    break someLabel;
  // more code
}
```

That works like a "goto" to the next statement after the outer `if` statement. You can't do that with `continue` because `continue` only makes sense with iteration constructs.

Comment: Would it possible to break into "pointless" from a loop, was trying to figure out how does "Statement2" from MDN in my question make any relevance

Comment: @KiranVedula only if the loop is nested inside the labeled statement. I'll extend my answer to explain.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Although it is syntactically correct to label an "If" statement; I don't think that's an intended purpose of Labels. I could see many of the code analysis tools throw warnings when labeling an "If" statement

Comment: @KiranVedula well sure, it's basically a somewhat controlled form of `goto`, and code complicated enough to require that is probably questionable anyway.